# No identifier/primary key specified for Entity in doctrine 2

Tags: doctrine-orm, entity, zend-framework2

I am using Zend 2 Framework and I am trying to get data using Doctrine 2.

However the following error is coming in the Entity file.

**Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException**

**No identifier/primary key specified for Entity "Acl\Entity\Permission". Every Entity must have an identifier/primary key.**

How can I specify the primary key?

I am using the following code.

```php
/**
 * User Permissions
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="acl_permissions")
 * @property int $id
 * @property int $role_id
 * @property int $resource_id
 * @property string $action
 */
class Permission
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Role")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    public $role;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Resource")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="resource_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    public $resource;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    public $action;

    public function getRole()
    {
    return $this->role;
    }

    public function getResource()
    {
    return $this->resource;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you checked [the docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#identifiers-primary-keys)?

You can define a primary key by using the `@ORM\Id` annotation. In case the value is generated automatically (e.g. if using `auto_increment`), you also need to set the `@ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")` annotation.